# how to upload image in django CBV(class based Views)createviews

Tags: python, django, blogs

I have been working on creating a blog sharing application using Django.I am trying to add an image field so that users will be able to upload images and view them as posts. But the image is not getting uploaded. Django is not even throwing any errors. The code is running fine but the image is not getting uploaded.

I have tried adding "enctype" in the template, as well as making the necessary changes in urls.py. I have even specified the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings.py.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) I have added this in my urls.py.

My models.py

```
    from django.utils import timezone
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.urls import reverse


    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        content = models.TextField()
        date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, 
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='% 
                                 (app_label)s_%(class)s_related')
        picture = 

  models.ImageField(upload_to='images',default='default.png',null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title 

       def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse('project-home')
```

My Views.py

```
    class PostCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin,LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','content','picture']
        success_message = 'Your submission is sucessful!'
        def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

        def get_success_message(self):
            return self.success_message
```

the image is not getting uploaded. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your template. Are you correctly setting the `enctype` on the form element?

Comment: <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" encytpe="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Blog Post</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button href = "{% url 'project-home' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

Comment: You have a typo: `encytpe` instead of `enctype`.

Comment: Changed it...still no changes...

Answer (score 2):

in the form element add enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ......
    ......
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to create a form for the Post Model and add this form to the create view [form_class =PostForm] instead of the [model=Post]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class-based views you do something like this

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'post_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post-list')
```